# Return list item with nested ternary in React.js/JSX

Tags: ternary-operator, reactjs

I want my react component to return a list item depending on the type of object array that is fed to it (string array element versus non-string array element). Everything works except for the nested ternary part. The conditions are evaluated correctly, when I do `<li>{console.log(listValue2)}</li>` instead of `<li>{listValue2}</li>` , the correct value is logged. But the list item does not appear in the DOM or virtual DOM no matter which code I do. My code is also available at https://github.com/neallred/neallred/tree/master/src/components.

Any ideas?

List.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
export class List extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
        <div>
          {this.props.list.map(function(listValue, index){
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <h3>{listValue.title}</h3>
                <p>{listValue.description}</p>
                <ul>
                {(typeof listValue.highlights === 'object' ?
                  listValue.highlights.map(function(listValue2, index2){
                    (typeof listValue.highlights[index2] === 'string' ?
                     <li>{listValue2}</li>
                    :
                      <li>{listValue2.title}</li>
                    )
                  })
                :
                  <li>no highlights object/outside of nested conditional</li>
                )}
                </ul>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This.props.list structure (FixturesEducation.jsx):

```
import React from 'react';
import { List } from './List.jsx';
...

const researchAssistant = {
  title: 'Research Assistant Work',
  description: `Working for Professors...`,
  highlights: [
    'Ensured research replicability',
    'more strings here...',
    'Used Stata scripts to conduct quantitative analyses'
  ]
};

const math = {
  title: 'Mathematical Foundation',
  description: 'Via several math and economics courses...',
  highlights: [
    'Game Theory (Econ 478)',
    'more strings here...',
    'Calculus I (Math 112 equivalent)'
  ]
};
const economics478 = {
    title: 'Game Theory',
    highlights: [
      'several',
      'strings...'
    ]
};
const economics459 = {
  ...
};
const economics388 = {
  ...};
const economics382 = {
  ...
};
const economics = {
  title: 'Economics',
  description: 'I learned about...,
  highlights: [
    economics478,
    economics459,
    economics388,
    economics382
  ]
};
const politicalScience372 = {
  ...
};
const politicalScience376 = {
  ...
};
const politicalScience497r = {
  ...
};
const politicalScience470 = {
  ...
};
const politicalScience344 = {
  ...
};
const politicalScience = {
  title: 'Political Science',
  description: 'I learned a lot...',
  highlights: [
    politicalScience470,
    politicalScience497r,
    politicalScience376,
    politicalScience372,
    politicalScience344
  ]
};
const spanish = {
  title: 'Spanish Language',
  description: 'I obtained my Spanish Language certificate...'
};
const businessMinor = {
  title: 'Business Minor',
  description: 'I this minor, I learned...'
};

const FixturesEducation = {
  title: 'Education',
  description: 'I attended ...',
  highlights: [
    researchAssistant,
    math,
    economics,
    politicalScience,
    businessMinor,
    spanish

  ]
};
export { FixturesEducation };
```

Code calling List component (Education.jsx):

```
import React from 'react';
import { List } from './List.jsx';
...
import { FixturesEducation } from './FixturesEducation.jsx';
...

export class Education extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 panel' id='education'>
        <h1>{FixturesEducation.title}</h1>
        <List list ={FixturesEducation.highlights}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: show structure of `this.props.list`, please.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong off the top of my head but it is incredibly hard to read. Please consider pulling this into a bunch of smaller methods that each render small pieces. The error might become clear when formatted differently.

Comment: Also, unless you're doing something explicitly with the keys, you only need keys on the top-level item being iterated (so, the <div> at the top and the <li>s), and keys only have to be unique compared to their siblings (so the div can have the same key as the li, no problem)